# How to stop printing it again? (html, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

This code is for printing a table and it's working fine but the problem is that when I click on **print table button** it prints the table but when I clicked it again it again prints the same table below I want it to not work again until the new input values are given. once it should print table and then don't until new values are given. I also want it to be more responsive.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Multiplication Table</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style>
.mystyle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: coral;
    color: white;
    font-size: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<h2>MultiplicationTable</h2

<form action>
Table Number:<br>
<input type="text" id="TN" name="TableNumber">
<br>
Initial Number:<br>
<input type="text" id="IN" name="InitialNumber">
<br>
Ending Number:<br>
<input type="text" id="EN" name="EndingNumber">
</form>

<br><br>    



   

<button id="again" onclick="myTable()">Print Table</button>

<br><br>

<button id="Bordertoggle" onclick="Bordertoggle()">Add Alternate Row Style</button>

<tr>

<button id="Hovertoggle" onclick="Hovertoggle()">Add Hover Effect</button>

<br><br>

 <!-- <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"  id="displayTables">

</table> -->

<table class="table" id="displayTables" border="0">
<tr></tr>

</table>

<!-- <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="HoverTables" border="1">
<tr></tr>

</table> -->

<!-- <p id="MT"></p> -->
 

<script>

          
// function myFunction()
// {
// var text = "";
// var Number = document.getElementById("TN").value;
// var T;
// var I = document.getElementById("IN").value;
// var E = document.getElementById("EN").value;

// for (T = I; T <= E; T++) {


//      text += Number + "*" + T + "=" + Number*T + "<br>"; 

// }


// document.getElementById("MT").innerHTML = text;
// }

 // function generateTable()
 //    {
 //     //var myVar = prompt("A number?", "");
 //     var myVar = document.forms.multTables.x.value;
 //     var myString = "<tr><th>"+ myVar + " times tables</th></tr>";
 //     for (i=1; i<=myVar; i++) 
 //     {
 //        myString += "<tr><td>";
 //       myString += i+ " x " +myVar+ " = " +(i*myVar)+ "\n";
 //       myString += "</td></tr>";
 //     }
 //     document.getElementById('t').innerHTML = myString;
 //     return false;
 //    }

function myTable()
{

var Number = document.getElementById("TN").value;
var T;
var I = document.getElementById("IN").value;
var E = document.getElementById("EN").value;
var temp="";
for (T = I; T <= E; T++) {
temp+="<tr><td>"+Number+"</td><td>*</td><td>" + T + "</td><td>=</td><td>" + Number*T +"</td></tr>"; 
}

$("#displayTables").append(temp);


}

  function Bordertoggle() {
             var element = document.getElementById("displayTables");
            element.classList.toggle("table-bordered");
                var change = document.getElementById("Bordertoggle");
                if (change.innerHTML == "Add Alternate Row Style")
                {
                    change.innerHTML = "Remove Alternate Row Style";
                }
                else {
                    change.innerHTML = "Add Alternate Row Style";
                }
            }

function Hovertoggle() {
   var element = document.getElementById("displayTables");
   element.classList.toggle("table-hover");
    var change = document.getElementById("Hovertoggle");
                if (change.innerHTML == "Add Hover Effect")
                {
                    change.innerHTML = "Remove Hover Effect";
                }
                else {
                    change.innerHTML = "Add Hover Effect";
                }
}
    
</script>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove the button....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just **save the current value** in variable and when next time user clicks **check** if value matches then don't print otherwise print.

```js
var prevN, prevI, prevE;   //store value in this variable of previous state

function myTable() {

    var Number = document.getElementById("TN").value;
    var T;
    var I = document.getElementById("IN").value;
    var E = document.getElementById("EN").value;
    var temp = "";
    if (prevN !== Number || prevE !== E || prevI !== I) {  //here check if value is changed  or not
        prevN = Number;
        prevE = E;
        prevI = I;
        for (T = I; T <= E; T++) {
            temp += "<tr><td>" + Number + "</td><td>*</td><td>" + T + "</td><td>=</td><td>" + Number * T + "</td></tr>";
        }

        $("#displayTables").append(temp);
    }

}

function Bordertoggle() {
    var element = document.getElementById("displayTables");
    element.classList.toggle("table-bordered");
    var change = document.getElementById("Bordertoggle");
    if (change.innerHTML == "Add Alternate Row Style") {
        change.innerHTML = "Remove Alternate Row Style";
    } else {
        change.innerHTML = "Add Alternate Row Style";
    }
}

function Hovertoggle() {
    var element = document.getElementById("displayTables");
    element.classList.toggle("table-hover");
    var change = document.getElementById("Hovertoggle");
    if (change.innerHTML == "Add Hover Effect") {
        change.innerHTML = "Remove Hover Effect";
    } else {
        change.innerHTML = "Add Hover Effect";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Multiplication Table</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <style>
        .mystyle {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 25px;
            background-color: coral;
            color: white;
            font-size: 25px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <h2>MultiplicationTable</h2 <form action>
    Table Number:<br>
    <input type="text" id="TN" name="TableNumber">
    <br> Initial Number:<br>
    <input type="text" id="IN" name="InitialNumber">
    <br> Ending Number:<br>
    <input type="text" id="EN" name="EndingNumber">
    </form>

    <br><br>





    <button id="again" onclick="myTable()">Print Table</button>

    <br><br>

    <button id="Bordertoggle" onclick="Bordertoggle()">Add Alternate Row Style</button>

    <tr>

        <button id="Hovertoggle" onclick="Hovertoggle()">Add Hover Effect</button>

        <br><br>

        <!-- <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover"  id="displayTables">

</table> -->

        <table class="table" id="displayTables" border="0">
            <tr></tr>

        </table>

        <!-- <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="HoverTables" border="1">
<tr></tr>

</table> -->

        <!-- <p id="MT"></p> -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a var to your ajavascript, like

```
printed = 0;
```

once you print your table, do

```
printed = 1;
```

Print only

```
if ( printed == 0 )
    ....print
```

?

Edit:

```
printed=0; 
......
if(printed==0) { 
    $("#displayTables").append(temp); 
    printed=1; 
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me where to add this

Comment: see edited answer, and out of my head, no testing done...please clean your code next time before you put your question here, just remove the outcommented things and so on...